# #1067 - Invalid default value for 'bonusid' how can i fix this error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE bonus(
bonusid INT( 10 ) DEFAULT  '0' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
empid INT( 10 ) DEFAULT  '0' NOT NULL ,
datebonus DATE DEFAULT  '0000-00-00' NOT NULL ,
bonuspayment VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
note TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( bonusid )
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1067 - Invalid default value for 'bonusid'

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to give default value for a primary key with auto increment value. Since you have defined `bonusid` as a primary key and has  defined auto increment.So this will automatically create a new value for `bonusid` whenever a new record is inserted.So try like this

```
CREATE TABLE bonus(
   bonusid INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   empid INT( 10 ) DEFAULT  '0' NOT NULL ,
   datebonus DATE DEFAULT  '0000-00-00' NOT NULL ,
   bonuspayment VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
   note TEXT NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( bonusid )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

default value is not allowed to the primary key because of if you used default value to primary key then some time the record is inserted as same and primary key is not allowed to insert same value in this column.

check this

```
CREATE TABLE bonus(
bonusid INT( 10 )  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
empid INT( 10 ) DEFAULT  '0' NOT NULL ,
datebonus DATE DEFAULT  '0000-00-00' NOT NULL ,
bonuspayment VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
note TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( bonusid )
);
```

if you use some column as primary key then it is default not null is not use to declare this. 
refer this link  for auto increment

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Even though the **`bonusid`** column is **`NOT NULL`** - you don't have to
>   specify a **`default value`** if it has the special **`auto_increment`** option
>   when you `create` the `table`.

Try As follows:

```
CREATE TABLE bonus(
bonusid INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
empid INT( 10 ) DEFAULT  '0' NOT NULL ,
datebonus DATE DEFAULT  '0000-00-00' NOT NULL ,
bonuspayment VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
note TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( bonusid )
);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd9c1)**