# I got error while entering the primary key in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Right now, i've created database with having 10 columns in my database but i can't create the database table and i got "#1067 - Invalid default value for 'primary_key" error.

Here is my sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz`.`user_details` ( `primary_key` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AUTO_INCREMENT , `foreign_key` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AUTO_INCREMENT , `firstname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `lastname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `phone_number` INT(10) NOT NULL , `address` CHAR(50) NOT NULL , `exam_taking` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`(6)), UNIQUE `foreign_key` (`foreign_key`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Remove `DEFAULT '1'` from your statement. You cannot default an auto-increment field in that manner.

Comment: remove the DEFAULT '1' and retry

Comment: and note that `'1'` is a string. to be proper it should be just `1`, making it a numeric literal.

Comment: After looking at your table definition, I *really* hope you're *not* planning to store user `password`s in plain text... you should use provide more space for *salted hashes* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add DEFAULT value because you already defined primary key as AUTO INCREMENT.
Possible duplicate.
[#1067 - Invalid default value for 'bonusid' how can i fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278484/1067-invalid-default-value-for-bonusid-how-can-i-fix-this-error)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a default value for auto incrementing fields. Simply change the definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz`.`user_details` 
  (`primary_key` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `foreign_key` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `firstname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
   `lastname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
   `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
   `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
   `email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
   `phone_number` INT(10) NOT NULL , 
   `address` CHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
   `exam_taking` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`), 
   UNIQUE `foreign_key` (`foreign_key`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Note also that a name `foreign_key` for an attribute which is *not* a foreign key is really misleading.