# Enum values and Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this error.

here is the code to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE `qa`.`question`(
  `id` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
  `phone` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `status` ENUM(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I see the same question , but none of them occur in my code .

I think about default value too , but I receive this:

> Invalid value for id (error #1067)

Comment: Your title says error 1064, but the error message is 1067. Which is it?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `enum(0)` ?

Comment: You generally shouldn't use numbers in `ENUM()`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html for the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error you got. I got a different error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NOT NULL,

This is because the elements of an `ENUM` must be strings, not numbers. I changed it to:

```
  `status` ENUM('OK', 'FAIL') NOT NULL,
```

and the table creation succeeded.

The error you got would happen if you tried to assign a default value to the `id` column, because it's also declared to use `AUTO_INCREMENT`. See [#1067 - Invalid default value for 'bonusid' how can i fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278484/1067-invalid-default-value-for-bonusid-how-can-i-fix-this-error)

Comment: thank's! I edited Enum value in phpMyAdmin , and there I write the string value , but in sql code I dont notice that its turn to number!! it's fix :)

Comment: ENUMs don't show up as numbers in SQL code, that's just the way they're stored in the database.